# PySpark broadcast variable for BlockMatrix

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working with 2 matrices, one dimensionally-reduced matrix of historical data and another that contains new data (both are in BlockMatrix data structures). I want to do what would be easy in numpy

```
ya=dot(oldDataMat,newDataMat[:,i])
```

but working in Spark I find I need to transpose the columns of the newData BlockMatrix so I can do a .map and then I found out I can't do a .map function that contains the oldDataMat BlockMatrix since it is not in the workers. So I'm wondering if A) there's an easier way to do what's easy in numpy or B) how do you broadcast a BlockMatrix in PySpark? The context is that I want to find the cosine similarity between the new data matrix and the old data matrix.

Thanks!

Comment: you cannot broadcast a block matrix since it is a distributed structure. However, you can do broadcast a numpy matrix. If your second matrix is not too big, you can parallelize bigger one and broadcast the smaller as numpy. For using map function, you can convert the matrix to IndexedRowMatrix and then into rdd. Can you show an example?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I actually decided to go with exactly your solution (though I came to it myself) and broadcast the numpy matrix since it isn't too big. Appreciate the help.